# passing forms data from one url to another url using POST method

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-post

I have 2 websites www.domain1.com & www.domain2.com. I want to pass some information from domain1 to domain2 using POST method using below code. But I am not getting anything in domain2. I am doing something wrong?

```
private void btnRedirect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strUsername = "Some Text Values Here";
    string outputHTML = "<html>";
    outputHTML += "<head>";
    outputHTML += "<title>Test</title>";
    outputHTML += "</head>";
    outputHTML += "<body>";
    outputHTML += "<center><h1>Please do not refresh this page...</h1></center>";
    outputHTML += "<form method='post' action='http://localhost:63064/userInfo.aspx' name='f1'>";
    outputHTML += "<input type='text' name='myUsername' value='" + strUsername + "' />";
    outputHTML += "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    outputHTML += "document.f1.submit();";
    outputHTML += "</script>";
    outputHTML += "</form>";
    outputHTML += "</body>";
    outputHTML += "</html>";
    Response.Write(outputHTML);
}
```

In domain2 I have beolow code

aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" name="f1"></form>
```

code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string ID = string.Empty;
    if (Request.Form.Count > 0) {
        ID = Request.Form("myUsername");
    }
    ID = (ID.Trim());

    Response.Write(ID);
}
```

UPDATE

```
Using WebClient to POST Data to another url
string strUsername = username.Text;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    dynamic reqparm = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
    reqparm.Add("myUsername", strUsername);
    byte[] responsebytes = client.UploadValues("http://localhost:63064/userInfo.aspx", "POST", reqparm);
    string responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
    Response.Redirect("/userInfo.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Use a `WebClient` to post data to another domain. Do NOT create a html page as a string.

Comment: @VDWWD please check above update made in my post. As you said I have used WebClient to post data.

Comment: Looks Ok at first glance. Does the data get posted?

Comment: @VDWWD No. Nothing getting posted from this. I am using same code as domain2 to fetch data from form

Comment: Tested your code. It works and posts data.

Comment: @VDWWD my code for fetching data is correct?

Comment: No that won't even compile: `Request.Form["myUsername"]`

Comment: So can you post where is the problem in code which fetch data. Please post in answer

Comment: Your code will capture the value of `myUsername` (when you replace the brackets). Remember that you won't see the output. The post is done in the background. Log form posts to a file or DB and you'll see